# Android: FrameAnimation and Bitmap size exceeds

Tags: android, animation, memory, bitmap

After reading a few posts in the stackoverflow site
I tried to build an animation by using a Frame animation

```
private void startAnimation(){
    fireAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
    fireAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fire1), 100);
    fireAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fire2), 100);
    fireAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fire3), 100);
    fireAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fire4), 100);
    ...
   fireAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fire16), 100);

}
```

Then in onCreate() I do startActivity();

```
But I have an error
02-12 13:31:31.909: E/dalvikvm-heap(4902): 1535664-byte external allocation too large for this process.
02-12 13:31:31.909: E/GraphicsJNI(4902): VM won't let us allocate 1535664 bytes
02-12 13:31:31.939: W/dalvikvm(4902): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at com.example.kersplatt.GameActivity.startAnimation(GameActivity.java:244)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at com.example.kersplatt.GameActivity.access$0(GameActivity.java:237)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at com.example.kersplatt.GameActivity$1.onTouch(GameActivity.java:80)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3881)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1738)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1127)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1722)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2196)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1880)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
02-12 13:31:31.959: E/AndroidRuntime(4902):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have 16images, when I put only 4 it works.
What could I do reduce the weight of the images? Should I reduce the size (600*650)m what's enough to have good quality?

Answer (score 0):

You can either reduce your image size
or 
You can try to increase you VM heap.

Try setting the following in adb shell.

**setprop dalvik.vm.heapsize "12m"**

Comment: But for reducing the size, how could I know which size is enought to fit in all the screens?

Comment: I am not much of an app developer. The problem is because the size of the images combined is more than VM heapsize. In your case your image size should be less than the heap size or you set a higher heap size. Actually you should have different images size for different screens. Are you running this in an emulator?